# No cargan las imagenes en mi pagina web

Tags: html, css, imagen

tengo el siguiente problema, en el editor de código cargo mi imagen y se ve genial perfecto 
pero cuando entro a la pagina directamente pulsando el archivo index.html no se ven las imagenes 
cargadas desde css. solo las que estan directamente en el html se pueden visualizar.

estoy voy chequeo las rutas, el nombre de la imagen que no tenga caracter especial sin espacios ni nada cargo y desde el editor si abro la pagina se visualiza bien.. pero si la abro desde 
el index.html haciendo click no puedo visualizar estas imagenes y tengo ese mismo problema 
en dos paginas que realize el dia de ayer...

he agotado todos los recursos y no encuentro la manera de resolver esto.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el trozo de código donde se está presentando el error?

Comment: Estas usando rutas relativas en tu css ?

Comment: El problema estaba en la ruta.